# Assigning float values: "incompatible type" error

Tags: objective-c

`vmdelivered.lastoutputter` is a `float` value and `vmdelivered.lastoutput` is an `NSString` which is getting converted into a `float` value. I tried to pass the value of `[vmdelivered.lastoutput floatValue]` to `vmdelivered.lastoutputter` using the code below. However I am getting the error:

```
Assigning to float* from incompatible type float
```

note the types are different (and in incompatible

Comment: "Assigning to **float\*** from incompatible type **float**" - note the types are different (and in incompatible).

Answer (score 3):

Read the error. It says your `lastoutputter` is defined as a pointer to float, but you're assigning a float value to it.

Comment: That depends on what you have control over. You have to understand what pointers are to continue working with Objective-C. If you know what a "definition is" and what a "pointer" is, you will know how to fix the error, since it tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: @user1795094 Get rid of the needless asterisk.

Comment: @user1795094 but if you don't understand *why* you will forever have problems with Objective-C (and other pointer-based languages)

Answer (score 0):

take out the asterisks in the method declarations.